# Postgresql 14 freezes when creating a new database

Tags: sql, postgresql, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I installed PostgreSQL on Windows WSL v14. When I create a new database, it freezes and nothing appears. I can create a table and new user row, but can't create a database.

[image]

Comment: Can you open another terminal and `tail -f` any logs?  Also, I would look at resource monitor and see if there are any hangups in disk I/O.

Comment: open a new session and look in pg_stat_activity and pg_locks.

Comment: Better to ask on sister site, https://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @MartinL.Brink i don't see anything.

Comment: @jjanes not found thso commend or files!! need install ??

Comment: @AlaaAqeel Those are views you can look at when connected to the database system (like from `psql`).  They exist automatically, and should be found in your search_path (unless you did something weird with your search_path).

Comment: I fixed this issue by reinstalling `wsl` ubuntu, thanks for comments.